# react material-ui npm install doesn't install devdependencies

Tags: material-ui

Whitout devdependencies, i've got some errors as babelrc need some plugins.

But, as I'm not intend to "dev" into it, I should not install/need this dev dependencies.. so perhaps, you should pass some of the needed deps into dependencies and not in devdependencies

Answer (score 0):

nope, it's not that, my bad, babel use every .babelrc, juste have to "exclude" node_modules folder in my webpack config.